# 2 argument numpy where function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, boolean-logic

I want 2 arguments for the where function in `numpy` but I know there is some kind of fault in my logic. For one argument I want it to have one column greater than `0` and selecting the same index from another column with blank entities.

```
august_report['Subsidy'] = np.where((august_report['Contract Renewal'] > 0)&(august_report['Transaction Types']== "NaN"), '1','0')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
august_report['Subsidy'] = np.where((august_report['Contract Renewal'] > 0)&(august_report['Transaction Types'].isnull()), '1','0')
```

or

```
august_report['Subsidy'] = np.where((august_report['Contract Renewal'] > 0)&(august_report['Transaction Types'] == ''), '1','0')
```

Your current code searches for `'NaN'` as a string, not as a blank value.